# Creating directory of shapefiles using gsconfig

Tags: python, geoserver-rest-api, gsconfig

I would like to use [gsconfig-py3 1.0.8](https://pypi.org/project/gsconfig-py3/) Python library to create a store that can receive multiple shapefiles, i.e. *"Directory of spatial files (shapefiles)"* (as it is in geosever), then add multiple shapefiles to it.

I am able to create a store by using the `create_featurestore` from `gsconfig`, however it result in a single shapefile store.

```py
from geoserver.catalog import Catalog
cat = Catalog(geoserver_uri + 'rest/', username="username", password="password")
data = r'../file.zip'
store = cat.create_featurestore("test", data, workspace=workspace)
cat.add_data_to_store(store, store.name, data, workspace)
```

If i try to add another shp it gives the error:

> geoserver.catalog.ConflictingDataError: There is already a store named

When I use the create_datastore the store type is not even specified on GeoServer under Data - Stores - Type, while Data Type has an exclamation sign.

```py
store = cat.create_datastore("test", workspace=workspace)
cat.add_data_to_store(store, store.name, data, workspace)
```

If I try to add a shapefile to it, I get:

> geoserver.catalog.FailedRequestError: Error code (500) from GeoServer:
> Store 'test' already exists in workspace

Comment: What happens if you use `overwrite=True/False` in `store = cat.create_featurestore("test", data, workspace=workspace, overwrite=True)`?

Comment: @Taras gsconfig-py3 1.0.8

Comment: @Taras It is working with overwrite=False, when creating the store and with cat.add_data_to_store(store, store.name, data, workspace, overwrite=True) when adding the data.  :)

Comment: looking through catalog.py I see nothing that looks like it handles directories of shapefiles, so you may need to extend gsconfig